# convert byte array block to DWORD (int) Java

Tags: java, decimal, block, endianness

How can I convert byte array block of 4 to integer number.

If we had these bytes of file in Hex Editor:

```
CB 01 00 00
```

The hexidecimal value of this block is DWORD of `000001CB` = `1CB`hex = `459` in decimal.

How can I convert any byte array (`byte[]`) block (of four bytes) to integer (decimal value of block)?

I am looking for method like this:

```
public int getDecimalFromBlock( byte... bytes ) {
      for ( byte b: bytes ) {
          // do the magic
      }
}
```

Where parameter byte in number between byte range (-127, 127).

Comment: Read it into a ByteBuffer, set the Byte Buffer’s order to LITTLE_ENDIAN, and call the ByteBuffer’s getInt method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume that your byte order is Little Endian (based on your post), and so the decoding will be

```
int value = ((data[0]&0xff) |
    ((data[1]&0xff)<<8) |
    ((data[2]&0xff)<<16) |
    ((data[3]&0xff)<<24));
```

If the order is Big endian, it will look something like:

```
int value = ((data[3]&0xff) |
    ((data[2]&0xff)<<8) |
    ((data[1]&0xff)<<16) |
    ((data[0]&0xff)<<24));
```

In both cases the variant "data" is a "byte[]"

```
byte[] data = new byte[] {(byte)0xcb, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00};
```

**Update to the edited request.**

I assume you may have problems with 0xcb as interpreted as negative value, this may be fixed by applying a `&` operator

Complete code with test case

```
public class DecimalTest
{
    public static int getDecimalFromBlock( byte... bytes ) {
        int result = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<bytes.length; i++)
        {
            result = result | (bytes[i] & 0xff)<<(i*8);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println(getDecimalFromBlock(new byte[]{(byte)0xcb}));
        System.out.println(getDecimalFromBlock(new byte[]{(byte)0xcb, 0x01}));
        System.out.println(getDecimalFromBlock(new byte[]{(byte)0xcb, 0x01, 0x00}));
        System.out.println(getDecimalFromBlock(new byte[]{(byte)0xcb, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00}));
        System.out.println(getDecimalFromBlock(new byte[]{(byte)0xcb, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}));
    }
}
```

Comment: How to put it to method? Updated my question.

Comment: EDIT: Do you have idea how to do it backwards ? From integer to byte block? I have issue converting hex "FE" (dec 254) to match byte range...

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at the Apache Commons IO library and its [EndianUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.2/org/apache/commons/io/EndianUtils.html) class. It is exactly for this purpose.

Please note that a four-byte DWORD (unsigned) can only correctly map to a Java (signed) `long`, as a Java (signed) `int` cannot hold every possible value of the DWORD (too large values would result in negative `int` values). So `EndianUtils.readSwappedUnsignedInteger()` correctly returns a `long`.